# Visual Studio 2015 - Team Fundation - Erro projeto Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Alguem está tendo problema para subir um projeto ASP.NET MVC para o Team Fundation?

O que acontece é que, faço o up, mas quando vou executar em outro computador, ele começa a dar erros de referencias `not found` percebi que realmente a pasta de referencia não esta sendo carregada quando faço o up pro servidor.

Alguém sabe de algo? ja nos projetos `WinForms` ocorre tudo normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é realmente a falta dos pacote Nuget, porém esse erro é gerado por ter subido o projeto de uma maneira incorreta para o Team Fondation.

Eu estava fazendo, pelo botão de "Add itens to Folder":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem o método correto para adicionar um novo projeto é utilizar o "Add Solution To Source Control"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A primeira opção deve ser usada, somente para incluir arquivos posteriores, documentos, imagens, arquivos complementares gerados por outro software e etc..

Para incluir soluções no Team Fondation deve ser utilizado o segundo método.

Comment: Isso mesmo. As vezes é as pequenas coisas que dão dor de cabeça e fazem a gente perder horas.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, pode ser mais especifico e dizer qual são as referencias não encontradas?

As vezes a ordem de compilação dos projetos na solution está errada.

Até lá, vc pode usar esse comando para baixar referencias faltando:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName You.Application.Name
```

Comment: Cara, são vários pacotes, vários mesmo.. ele só não da erro nos pacotes próprios do visual studio, de resto, em todos, mas acho que eu estava subindo de um jeito errado, estou subindo de uma outra maneira e já posto o resultado. vou tentar esse comando.

Comment: Talvez seja a falta dos pacotes Nuget do projeto, não é uma boa prática incluí-los no controle de versão, então sempre será necessário baixá-los ao baixar o código fonte pela primeira vez